# Reading robot.txt with jsoup line-by-line

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, robots.txt

I'm trying to read a robot.txt file using jsoup. I want to read this file line by line and identify whether a line is disallowed/allowed/useragent/sitemap.

Using Jsoup I do the following:

> > robotfile = Jsoup.connect(u).get();
> >
> > robotfile.text();

However, the latter gives me:

> > 80legs User-agent: 008 Disallow: / User-Agent: bender Disallow: /my_sh.. *etc*

Even if I do .html(), I can not see any linebreaks (e.g.  tags), so I am not able to replace all those values with a simple linebreak.

Is there a way to read this file line by line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSoup is really built for reading and parsing HTML files. The robots.txt file is not an HTML file and would be better to be read by a simple input stream. Here is a simple connection that reads Googles robots.txt file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://google.com/robots.txt").openStream()))) {
        String line = null;
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Output** (truncated due to length):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
Disallow: /sdch
Disallow: /groups
Disallow: /images
Disallow: /catalogs
...
```

Comment: But this will not read the rest of the disallowed paths if the robots.txt has line break somewhere in it, like this:

`user-agent: *

Disallow: /search


user-agent: bender

Disallow:/groups`

Am I right?

Comment: @SyedDanishAli no, the `readLine()` method only returns null if it is the end of the file. Otherwise it will return an empty string.

Comment: Thanks ug. That was just a misconception I had. I tried the code by myself and cleared the query. Thanks anyway.

Comment: But what if robot.txt file is not present there on the server. It will throw Input stream error.?